# Como posso juntar uma varíavel PHP para um Drag and Drop Canvas do Konva?

Tags: php, html

Estou fazendo um site em que ao clicar em um radio button, o valor dele (um id de uma variavel do sql) abrirá ao lado logo em seguida em um canvas, que assim você vai criando uma imagem. Minha ideia é usar o Drag and Drop Canvas do Konva:

```
<script>
    var width = window.innerWidth;
    var height = window.innerHeight;

    function drawImage(imageObj) {
        var stage = new Konva.Stage({
            container: 'container',
            width: width,
            height: height
        });

        var layer = new Konva.Layer();
        // darth vader
        var darthVaderImg = new Konva.Image({
            image: imageObj,
            x: stage.getWidth() / 2 - 200 / 2,
            y: stage.getHeight() / 2 - 137 / 2,
            width: 200,
            height: 137,
            draggable: true
        });

        // add cursor styling
        darthVaderImg.on('mouseover', function() {
            document.body.style.cursor = 'pointer';
        });
        darthVaderImg.on('mouseout', function() {
            document.body.style.cursor = 'default';
        });

        layer.add(darthVaderImg);
        stage.add(layer);
    }
    var imageObj = new Image();
    imageObj.onload = function() {
        drawImage(this);
    };
    imageObj.src = 'http://konvajs.github.io/assets/darth-vader.jpg';
</script>
```

Pensei em usar o Ajax, mas não sei como funcionará. Qual seria  a melhor forma?